# How can I record a transition from an "Off" to an "On" in a column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

This question has its roots here:

[How can I record a transition from a 0 to 1 in a column in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/847627/how-can-i-record-a-transition-from-a-0-to-1-in-a-column-in-excel?newreg=f259fabc5b1145f0a0e4f91cc3eae3f3)

But, instead of zeroes and ones, I'd like to use On/Off as my switching parameter.

The code should scan a column. Every time it sees "Off" immediately followed by an "On," count it.

I could very well convert the column of strings to zeroes and ones and apply the answer above, but... I was wondering if there was something less clunky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A12="off")*(--(A2:A13="on")))`
Use this formula where A1:A13 is the column where you have on, off all the Rows
in the A1:A12="off" is your column without the last Row
and A2:A13="on" is your column without the first Row
The Formula will count the off following with on
**Update**
In E1 write `A1:A12`
In E2 write `A2:A13`
and use this Formula:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT(E1)="off")*(--(INDIRECT(E2)="on")))`
You can change E1 and E2 to a different references

Comment: This works well. However, I forgot to specify that the length of my columns is variable. Let's say I have stored the number of the last row of data in a variable called LR. How would I adjust your code to accommodate this variation? I have tried =SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A & LR)="off")*(--((A2:A & LR)="on"))), though when it calculates something is off and all I see is #NAME? in the final sum cell.

Comment: You have to use Indirect as function in the formula, read the Update of the answer

Comment: Be aware that `INDIRECT` is a volatile function, meaning that it will recalculate every time you modify the contents of any cell. This will have a major performance impact in huge workbooks.

Comment: Maybe it is better to write the references directly without Indirect

Comment: You guys have already done enough. Thank you for the help. I will take it from here.